# How can one block a query string while running a forward proxy using the mod_proxy in apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, networking, server, proxy, mod-proxy

I have tried using the ProxyBlock directive in mod_proxy it blocks only domain names but does not block query strings like the query strings google generates as an example.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please review the [guidelines for posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The first point of the guidelines is to do research before posting a new question. Then, the title should be well descriptive of the question you are asking, and the question text must include much more information: you need to introduce well the context, without just posting the error/problem, and you need the right amount of code to let others understand/reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.